# How to apply custom height and width of visuals?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have 10 visuals in my embedded report. I want to remove the some specific visuals and want to set the height and width of the remaining visuals to make the fit to the report. Is it possible to set the height and width of visuals after removing or hiding visuals?

Comment: Check out the Report Authoring API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-authoring-overview

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by applying custom layout to your report. You can hide all the visuals and then show only the required visuals with updated height and width. To hide the visuals you can set the mode as Hidden in page Layout.
Please find the below code snippet:

1. Hide all the visuals and set height and width of report page:

```js
const defaultLayout = {
    width: "Required_Width",
    height: "Required_Height",
    displayState: {
        mode: models.VisualContainerDisplayMode.Hidden
    }
};
```

2. Update height and width of your required visual:

```js
const pageLayout = {
    defaultLayout: defaultLayout,
    visualsLayout: {
        "Required_Visual_Name": {
            x: "Required_Width",
            y: "Required_Height",
            displayState: {
                mode: models.VisualContainerDisplayMode.Visible
            }
        },
    }
};
```

3. Update the settings:

```js
const settings = {
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
    customLayout: {
        displayOption: models.DisplayOption.FitToPage,
        pagesLayout: {
            "Your_Report_Id": pageLayout
        }
    },
}
```

4. Apply the settings:

```js
await report.updateSettings(settings);
```

You can refer the Personalize top insights showcase in Power BI Playground:https://playground.powerbi.com/showcases-gallery/personalize-top-insights

You get the code reference for this showcase here:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Embedded-Showcases/tree/main/Personalize%20top%20insights

Please find the reference here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/custom-layout